# How to bind dates list datagridtextcolumn with Ivalueconverter

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ivaluecon"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Grid.Row="1"   AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" Margin="25,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="744">
        <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding d, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid>
  <DatePicker x:Name="sdate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="66,312,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="edate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="272,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="148"/>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Margin="452,308,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155"/>
</Grid>
```

I am not able to understand how to bind datelist columns.

class

```
Public Class YesNoToBooleanConverter

Implements IValueConverter

Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
    If value.tstring() = "true" Then
        Return "Yes"
    Else
        Return "No"
    End If
End Function


Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
    Return New Object()
End Function
```

Here is my code for generating dateslist columns

```
Class MainWindow
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim daysList As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim d As DateTime = New DateTime(2020, 12, 1)
    While d <= New DateTime(2020, 12, 14)
        Dim columnName As String = d.ToString("dd.MM")
        daysList.Columns.Add(columnName, GetType(Boolean))
        Dim dd As DataGridTextColumn = New DataGridTextColumn() With {
.Header = columnName,
.Binding = New Binding("[" & columnName & "]")
}
        dg.Columns.Add(dd)
        d = d.AddDays(1)
    End While
    Dim truth = String.Format("{0:on;0;OFF}", True.GetHashCode())
    Dim unTruth = String.Format("{0:on;0;OFF}", False.GetHashCode())
    For r As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1
        Dim row = daysList.NewRow()
        For c As Integer = 0 To daysList.Columns.Count - 1
            row(c) = (c Mod (r + 1)) = 0
        Next
        daysList.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    dg.ItemsSource = daysList.DefaultView
End Sub
End Class
```

Someone help me how to bind datelist column with xaml. Please have a look once and give me any example on this issue to fix this. thankyou....

below is the screenshot of dateslist and columns are having True and False I need to change as Yes and No.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i72KO.jpg)

Comment: In case you need to convert *from* boolean *to* string ("yes"/"no"), you have got the converter wrong. Exchange the implementations of Convert and ConvertBack.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I edit the convert code class. Could you please tell me how to bind dates generated columns. thanks....

Comment: Can anyone help on this issue... thanks....

Comment: @PVimala, since you creates columns and bindings in code, add converter to those bindings (I mean `.Binding = New Binding("[" & columnName & "]")`). I can only suggest c# equivalent: `Binding = new Binding($"[{columnName}]") { Converter = new YesNoToBooleanConverter() }`

Comment: Thank you so much sorry for the late reply. I am working on this....